# Keeping only one ID # per month in R

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a data frame that consists of a lot of ID #'s and their transaction data for the entire year. There are a lot of duplicates amongst the ID's and I want to get rid of them, but I want to have one ID per month. If I use the [!duplicated...] function it gets rid of all the ID's after january as well. Any ideas?

Here is what i have:

```
Date        ID   Transaction
1/31/2016   111     10
1/31/2016   111     12
1/31/2016   112     15
2/28/2016   111     50
2/28/2016   112     40
2/28/2016   112     3
```

This is what I would like:

```
Date        ID   Transaction1  Transaction 2
1/31/2016   111      10           12
1/31/2016   112      15            -
2/28/2016   111      50            -
2/28/2016   112      40            3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I know that `spread` *should* be the way to do this, I have never been able to get it to work. I'm sure Hadley Wickham is unhappy this, but what I do with problems like this is `paste` all the value of `Transaction` that you want to spread into a single string with `summarize`, then split that string into columns using `separate`

Note that as in your example, we've grouped by Date. If you actually want to group by Month, then you'd need to use `lubridate` to extract a month value from your Date variable.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dates %>%
    group_by(ID, Date) %>%
    summarize(ntrans = length(Transaction),
              transactions = paste0(Transaction, collapse = '-')) %>%
    separate(transactions,
             into = paste0('Transaction', seq_len(max(.$ntrans))),
             sep = '-', fill = 'right') %>%
    select(-ntrans)


# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID Date      Transaction1 Transaction2
  <int> <fct>     <chr>        <chr>       
1   111 1/31/2016 10           12          
2   111 2/28/2016 50           NA          
3   112 1/31/2016 15           NA          
4   112 2/28/2016 40           3
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `spread`

```
library(tidy verse)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Date, ID) %>%
    mutate(new = paste0("Transaction", row_number())) %>%
    spread(new, Transaction)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   Date, ID [4]
#  Date         ID Transaction1 Transaction2
#  <chr>     <int>        <int>        <int>
#1 1/31/2016   111           10           12
#2 1/31/2016   112           15           NA
#3 2/28/2016   111           50           NA
#4 2/28/2016   112           40            3
```

Comment: The dataset that I am using has thousands and thousands of observations. This did slightly what I wanted but it gave me 3 ID's per month and also gave me many extra columns

Comment: @hanz Sorry, missed the 'Date' in the `group_by`.  Now, it should work

Comment: That fixed all the extra columns however I am still getting 3 ID's per month

Comment: If this isn't working for you, you might need to give us a larger sample of data. From the data you've provided, this seems like a reasonable solution, but 3 IDs per month is a scenario that isn't covered by the sample

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility using `data.table` package:

```
data.table::dcast(dat[, Tx := paste0("Tx", rowid(ID)), by=.(Date)], 
    Date + ID ~ Tx, value.var="Transaction")
```

output:

```
        Date  ID Tx1 Tx2
1: 1/31/2016 111  10  12
2: 1/31/2016 112  15  NA
3: 2/28/2016 111  50  NA
4: 2/28/2016 112  40   3
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- fread("Date        ID   Transaction
1/31/2016   111     10
1/31/2016   111     12
1/31/2016   112     15
2/28/2016   111     50
2/28/2016   112     40
2/28/2016   112     3")
```